# check null parameters in where at entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to make one query can check if parameters is null or not to confirm action, look at this method to understand what i mean :

```
private List<CE_ProductBoxViewModel> GetProductList(bool? isDeal, int? catId, int? brandId, int? takeNum)
        {
            List<CE_ProductsLoc> moduleItems = db.CE_ProductsLoc
                .Include(x => x.CE_Products)
                .Include(x => x.CE_Products.CE_ProductsImages)
                .Include(x => x.CE_Products.CE_ProductsRates)
                .Where(x => x.CE_Products.TypeId == 12
                    && x.LanguageId == LangId
                    if(isDeal != null){&& x.CE_Products.IsDeal == isDeal})
                .Take(takeNum ?? int.MaxValue)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.CE_Products.NumOrder)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.ProductId).ToList();
        }
```

i know its incorrect, but i want to check if parameter is null, don't allow it in where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can work on your queryable like this :

```
 //here var was an OrderedQueryable because order was the last clause
 IQueryable<CE_ProductsLoc> moduleItems = db.CE_ProductsLoc
                .Include(x => x.CE_Products)
                .Include(x => x.CE_Products.CE_ProductsImages)
                .Include(x => x.CE_Products.CE_ProductsRates)
                 .Where(x => x.CE_Products.TypeId == 12
                    && x.LanguageId == LangId)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.CE_Products.NumOrder)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.ProductId);
 if(isDeal != null){
 moduleItems = moduleItems.Where(x =>x.CE_Products.IsDeal == isDeal);
 }
//executed only here
 List<CE_ProductsLoc> list = moduleItems.Take(takeNum ?? int.MaxValue).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but i know this solution, and this solution will not make best performance with big data, i want to know if there are any way to get my specific data in one query ?

Comment: @AhmadAlaa 
 
i'm not sure you understood. there is only one query here, when .ToList() is called because until the last line modulesItems is just a IQueryable and don't execute any query

Comment: Oh sorry :) , ill try and feedback

Comment: This line : moduleItems = moduleItems.Where(x =>x.CE_Products.IsDeal == isDeal);  gives me error

Comment: this is error message : cannot implicitly convert type system.linq.iqueryable to system.linq.iorderedqueryable

Comment: i think that this error occurs because orderby must be final query ?

Comment: Please, take a look at the next answer i posted now :)

Comment: @AhmadAlaa i made an edit on my answer that works too

Comment: `orderby` don't need to be final if you explicitly use an IQueryable

Comment: Thank you, but what about my answer ? is that work also as one query ?

Answer (score 0):

According to @Emmanuel M. conversation, i think that is the right answer for best performance, if anyone have other answer, please share with us

```
private List<CE_ProductBoxViewModel> GetProductList(bool? isDeal, int? catId, int? brandId, int? takeNum)
        {
            var items = db.CE_ProductsLoc
                .Include(x => x.CE_Products)
                .Include(x => x.CE_Products.CE_ProductsImages)
                .Include(x => x.CE_Products.CE_ProductsRates)
                .Where(x => x.CE_Products.TypeId == 12
                    && x.LanguageId == LangId
                    && x.CE_Products.IsActive == true)
                .Take(takeNum ?? int.MaxValue);
            if (isDeal != null)
                items = items.Where(x => x.CE_Products.IsDeal == isDeal);
            if (catId != null)
                items = items.Where(x => x.CE_Products.CatId == catId);
            if (brandId != null)
                items = items.Where(x => x.CE_Products.BrandId == brandId);
            List<CE_ProductsLoc> moduleItems = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.CE_Products.NumOrder).ThenByDescending(x => x.ProductId).ToList();
        }
```